# How to convert properly an object to KeyValuePair.Key?

Tags: c#, dictionary, casting, type-conversion, key-value

I am struggling with converting an `object` to `KeyValuePair.Key`. In my method I have signature:

```
public EstimatorChain<RegressionPredictionTransformer<PoissonRegressionModelParameters>> GetRegressionPipeline(MLContext context, KeyValuePair<Type, object> algorithm)
```

And casting: `(algorithm.Key)algorithm.Value` or `algorithm.Value as algorithm.Key` throws me an exception:

> algorithm is a variable but is used like a type

How to convert it properly to the `Key` type? Assuming that `Value` is `LbfgsPoissonRegressionTrainer something = new LbfgsPoissonRegressionTrainer();`

Comment: This is because you can't cast something to a *variable* even if that variable is of type `Type`. If you *really* want to do this then you'll need to use [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) for everything you want to do on that `object`

Comment: I still do not get it, how should I reflect on the `Key`, assuming that, for the example `Key` is `typeof(LbfgsPoissonRegressionTrainer)`, or the `object` is `LbfgsPoissonRegressionTrainer something = new LbfgsPoissonRegressionTrainer()`?

Comment: What is the actual problem? are you trying to call a method and have trouble supplying arguments? Or do you want to use the key-property of a keyValyuePair for something?

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions of my question.

First is just to cast on `EstimatorChain<RegressionPredictionTransformer<PoissonRegressionModelParameters>>` type:

```
(IEstimator<RegressionPredictionTransformer<PoissonRegressionModelParameters>>)algorithm.Value
```

Another one is to use `var value = Convert.ChangeType(item.Value, item.Key);`:

```
.Append((dynamic)Convert.ChangeType(algorithm.Value, algorithm.Key));
```